# Insert an element in every position of a List - ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, permutation

I'm trying to write a function which insert an integer n in every position of a given list. Little example, `insert_everywhere 0 [1;2] -> [[0;1;2]; [1;0;2]; [1;2;0]]`. I wrote this :

```
let insert_everywhere l n  = 
  let l_aux = [] in 
  let rec aux l1 l2 = match l1 with
    | [] -> []
    | x::tl -> (l_aux @ [n] @ l1) :: aux tl (l_aux @ [x])
  in aux l l_aux
;;
```

The probleme is that calling `aux tl (l_aux @ [x])` doesn't do what I want. My idea is: when I'm reading the head of my list, I insert into an another list which I append to the number `n` and the rest of the list. With this way, I will have the final list of list that I excepted but not with my current implementation…

Comment: Don't you mean `insert_everywhere [1;2] 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution is strongly related to data structure called `zipper`. You need to keep not evaluated  tail of list if 1st argument of `aux` and also keep evaluated prefix of list to build a part of answer of it. You don't need `l_aux`, we will use 2nd argument instead of using mutable variable. Let's look at skeleton

```
let insert_everywhere l (n : int)  =
  let rec aux l1 l2 : int list list = match l1 with
  | [] ->  (* There we need to built a part of answer 
              from l1 prefix, n and empty tail postfix*)
  | x::tl -> (* There we need to construct part of answer *) 
             :: aux tl ( (* construct new prefix from old one and `n` there *) )
  in
  aux l []
```

If you still can't find answer you can look at my solution [there](http://paste.in.ua/9000/raw/). I will add it to my answer when you will find an answer. Try not to peep into link! :)

P.S.

```
let insert_everywhere l (n : int)  =
  let rec aux l1 l2 = match l1 with
  | [] -> [l2 @ [n]]
  | x::tl -> (l2 @ [n] @ l1) :: aux tl (l2 @ [x])
  in
  aux l []
```

Comment: Arf ... thank you for your help. I was sure that I need to use an another list for to have the prefix list and it ... Thank's a lot :)

Comment: `li @ [v]` is an antipattern in list programming, as it takes linear time instead of constant time as `v :: li`. You should rewrite all those occurrences as `v :: li`, and then use `List.rev` and `List.rev_append` as appropriate to get the expected order back.